# how to set formula in column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem with setting the formula in particular field. I am using sql database have been added from->add new item->sql database. I have orders table with following field:

```
ordernum primary key  
orderdate smalldatetime,  
custemail varchar(50),  
subtotal money,  
salestax money,  
shipping money,  
total AS(subtotal+salestax+shipping)
```

How to set this total formula, there is no datatype mentioned in total field.

Thanks,
Habib

Comment: A good, if a bit long, discussion on why or why not to have calculated fields in a DB:  http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies-archive.cfm/536304.html

Answer (score 1):

This example should illustrate what you are looking to achieve.

```
  create table #table
    (
        ordernum int identity(1,1) primary key,
        orderdate smalldatetime,
        custemail varchar(50),
        subtotal money, 
        salestax money, 
        shipping money, 
        total AS(subtotal+salestax+shipping)
    )

    insert into #table
    (
        orderdate,
        custemail,
        subtotal, 
        salestax, 
        shipping 
    )
    select
        getDate(),
        'some@email.com',
        1.00,
        1.00,
        1.00

    select * from #table

    drop table #table
```

cheers, John